# relativelayout and togglebutton

Tags: android

This my main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/gloabal_permission"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/settings_selector_down"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp" android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                        android:paddingRight="12dp" android:paddingLeft="15dp">
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView06"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Gloabal permission" android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                        </TextView>
                        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/globalpermissionbutton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="ToggleButton" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
                        </ToggleButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

What should I do so when I click on relativelayout togglebutton is turn on (click one more time toggle button is turn off). I just wnat tie up relativelayoutlistener with togglebutton's listener.

Comment: You are saying that this toggle button is not setting to on or off when you tap it?

Comment: I just want to see any example how to do it.

Comment: But your example is not working?

Comment: I don't have any example, I tried do it myself. I have seen example with listview but I don't have listview in myapp. it is only relativelayout.

Comment: when I tap on togglebotton is setting on or off. I want tap in layout and togglebutton set on or off automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a onClick() listener for your relative layout for that.
Eg.

```
yourRelLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener({
  yourToggleButton.setChecked(true);
}));
```

and that is all :)

Good luck!