# RelativeLayout inside a ToggleButton?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

What's the best way to put a RelativeLayout **inside** a ToggleButton? If it matters, the RelativeLayout has a bunch of TextViews contained within.

This question is similar to [relativelayout and togglebutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353510/relativelayout-and-togglebutton) , but with a subtle difference. In the referenced question, the user has put a TextView with a ToggleButton inside a RelativeLayout. In my case I want to put the RelativeLayout inside the ToggleButton so that I don't have to add an onClickListener to the RelativeLayout.

Is this possible only by extending CompoundButton?

**Edit:** What's the best way to create a widget/view with ToggleButton-like functionality where the on/off text can be replaced by any other widget/view/viewgroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a RelativeLayout inside a ToggleButton.

ToggleButton is a `View` and RelativeLayout is a `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Thanks @gwa , what's the best way to create a ToggleButton where instead of the text I can put any widget/ViewGroup? (edited the question)

Comment: No problem Saurabh! Well, it depends what you want to do, if you have a super specif behavior that you want to implement, then you need to write a custom view. Otherwise, I think that the easiest solution would be to include the ToggleButton in a layout, for example a RelativeLayout, so you can build whatever complex layoyut. Then you make the ToggleButton itself not clickable while the parent layout is clickable. Then based on the onClick of the parent layout you change the status of the ToggleButton. Hope it will help!

Comment: ps. it would be nice if you marked the answer as correct, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible only by extending CompoundButton?

That will not work either. `CompoundButton` is not a `ViewGroup`, so it cannot hold widgets.

> What's the best way to create a widget/view with ToggleButton-like functionality where the on/off text can be replaced by any other widget/view/viewgroup?

This would be a completely custom `View` or `ViewGroup`.